# How to track the source of non-targeted RHEL traffic from sssd?

Tags: linux, ip, rhel, tcpdump, netstat

I have sssd for connecting to LDAP server.
In sssd.conf ldap_uri=target_server.com

But using tcpdump i see non-targeted and targeted traffic to ldap port. When the sssd is stopped non-target and targeted traffic stopped too. This means that the traffic source is associated with sssd.
How can i track what is the source of traffic if sssd.conf configured correctly?

I tried to track the source by port. Used netstat -tulpn for this, but port is switching so fast that I couldn't keep up.